# MicrosoftEdge - WebDriver - error when I try to use SelectElement

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm getting "unknown error" when I tried to set a Support.UI.SelectElement using the MicrosoftEdge driver. This is working fine for IE, Chrome and Firefox.

I'm using Selenium C# 2.47.

**Example code**:

```
dim e As OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement
e = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id))
dim combo As OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement
combo = New OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(e)
```

> **Error message**: unknown error
>
> **StackTrace**: at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)      at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)      at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)      at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String
>   commandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)      at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAttribute(String
>   attributeName)     at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement..ctor(IWebElement element)

Anyone has a workaround for it?

Thanks,
Cristian